# Android Instant Apps: YouTube Android Player not compatible?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api, android-instant-apps

I'm developing an Android Instant App that uses the YouTube Android Player library, however it is not allowing me to initialize the player. When I try to load a video I get this message asking me to install the YouTube app, (which I already have). This could be a restriction of Instant Apps, but I'm not sure because the docs aren't too clear about this particular issue. In my logcat I also get a `SERVICE_MISSING` message. Any insight would be great thanks.

[image]

Comment: Upon clicking the "Get YouTube App" what happens? does it takes to playstore with "Install/Update" button?

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what happens. Except no install button (cause I already have it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got back an email from Google and as of this posting, the YouTube Android Player is not compatible w/ Instant Apps.

Comment: That is correct. I don’t see it listed as part of https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html#identify_tested_compatible_libraries. This list should be growing though.